# Why does my LSTM autoencoder model couldn't detect outliers?

Tags: deep-learning, lstm, autoencoder, anomaly-detection

I am trying to build a LSTM Autoendoer for anomaly detection.

But the model seems not work for my data.

Here is the normal data that I use it for training.

[image: TrainData]

And here is abnormal data that I use it for validation.

[image: Valid]

If model works, its loss should be high at #200000~#500000.

Unfortunately, here is the result I put the valid data to the model:

[image: Result]

In the abnormal interval, the loss still low.

Here is my code of training model.

I would greatly appreciate it if you kindly give me any suggestions.

```
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
scaler.fit(healthy_data)
data_scaled = scaler.transform(healthy_data)
data_broken_scaled = scaler.transform(broken_data)

timesteps=32
data = data_scaled 
dim = 1
data.shape = (-1,timesteps,dim)   

lr = 0.0001
Nadam = optimizers.Nadam(lr=lr)

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(50,input_shape=(timesteps,dim),return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dense(dim))

model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer=Nadam ,metrics=['mse'])

EStop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0.001,patience=150, verbose=2, mode='auto',restore_best_weights=True)

history = model.fit(data,data,validation_data=(data,data),epochs=3000,batch_size=72,verbose=2,shuffle=False,callbacks=[EStop]).history

pred_broken = model.predict(data_broken_scaled)
loss_broken = np.mean(np.abs(pred_broken-data_broken_scaled),axis=1)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 6), dpi=80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
ax.plot(range(0,len(loss_broken)), loss_broken, '-', color='red', animated = True, linewidth=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I Think, it may better to use Fourier transform to detect anomaly in frequency view.
I means, the train and test data will be converted to frequency domain via Fourier transform. Also I recommend to use Time-windows.
Most AI will act better if they have enough good train data. Your anomaly points should be labeled to 1(by pre-processing step of the data) and it should have high frequency at your time-step(time-windows).

In short, I think your train data may not sufficiently representative for anomaly now.